# Selenium wont return text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I have this code which is referencing this html class:

```
<div class="text-right _2jRRJJvarKXJGP9oRP-Bv0 pbBzNArud8-t5yrNZi8Wg rankings-list-volume">2775.60</div>
```

```
Vol = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/main/div/div/div[2]/a[1]/div[8]').text
print(Vol)
```

If I run it without the .text it returns just the element name and such so I know it is finding the element but it won't return the text. The `2775.60` value within the HTML is what it should be returning but instead, it just prints nothing.

Comment: HTML keeps formatting wrong in the post but the html code is "<div class="text-right _2jRRJJvarKXJGP9oRP-Bv0 pbBzNArud8-t5yrNZi8Wg rankings-list-volume">2769.94</div>"

Comment: Don't worry I put an edit on it.

Answer (score 3):

To print the text **2769.94** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.rankings-list-volume").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'rankings-list-volume')]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the text **2769.94** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rankings-list-volume"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'rankings-list-volume')]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)